# Call Eax in IDA PRO

Tags: ida, assembly

My situation:

I analyze some piece of code and I have the following line:

```
         ...
         call eax
         ...
```

I am using IDA PRO. My problem is that I can not go to the place where eax points. I mean: normally, I have something like

```
        ...
        call sub_xxxxxx
        ...
```

and when I click on sub_xxxxxx, then IDA PRO shows me the code at sub_xxxxxx. Sometimes, there is also an offset. 
But now, I have that register, and when I click on that then IDA PRO is not going to that location. It opens a window where I can rename the register. 
I guess, IDA does not know where to go or something like that.

I also try to open it with ollydbg, but since the file is a .bin file, I could not open it(in the search window, before opening, the .bin file was not listed)

How can I handle that problem ?

Comment: To address the Olly issue, you could just rename the bin file to .exe so Olly sees it.

Answer (score 5):

You would need to statically determine what the value(s) of `eax` could be by statically reverse engineering the surrounding code, or (if you can run the target in a debugger) set a breakpoint on that `call eax` instruction and see what value of `eax` is used at runtime.

Note that for the dynamic approach, different runtime scenarios may cause `eax` to hold different values at that instruction address at runtime.

Comment: ok, thx. Is there a way to open the .bin file using ollydbg?

Comment: If the .bin file is actually a PE EXE or PE DLL, then yes. Just manually specify the full file path of the file in OllyDbg's open-file dialog box. Or drag-and-drop the file into OllyDbg's MDI client window.